# Rails has_many :through, cocoon

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nested-forms, has-many-through, cocoon-gem

## Player.rb

```
class Player < ApplicationRecord
belongs_to :user
has_many :player_games, dependent: :destroy, inverse_of: :player
has_many :games, :through => :player_games

validates :firstname, presence: true, length: { minimum: 3, maximum: 88 }
validates :lastname, presence: true, length: { minimum: 3, maximum: 88 }
validates :user_id, presence: true

accepts_nested_attributes_for :player_games, reject_if: :reject_posts, allow_destroy: true

def reject_posts(attributes)
    attributes['game_id'].to_i == 0
    attributes['score'].blank?
    attributes['time'].blank?
end

def initialized_player_games # this is the key method
    [].tap do |o|
        Game.all.each do |game|
            if g = player_games.find { |g| g.game_id == game.id }
                o << g.tap { |g| g.enable ||= true }
            else
                o << PlayerGame.new(game: game)
            end
        end
    end
end
end
```

## players_controller.rb

```
class PlayersController < ApplicationController
before_action :set_player, only: [:edit, :update, :show, :destroy]
before_action :require_user, except: [:index, :show]
before_action :require_same_user, only: [:edit, :update, :destroy]

before_filter :process_player_games_attrs, only: [:create, :update]

def process_player_games_attrs
  params[:player][:player_games_attributes].values.each do |game_attr|
    game_attr[:_destroy] = true if game_attr[:enable] != '1'
  end
end
```

.......

```
private
  # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
  def set_player
    @player = Player.find(params[:id])
  end

  # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
  def player_params
    params.require(:player).permit(:id, :firstname, :lastname, player_games_attributes: [:id, :game_id, :score, :time, :enable, :_destroy] )
  end

  def require_same_user
    if current_user != @player.user and !current_user.admin?
      flash[:danger] = "You can edit or delete only your own player"
      redirect_to root_path
    end 
  end

end
```

## _form of 'PLAYER'

```
<%= form_for(@player, :html => {class: "az-form", role: "form"}) do |player_form| %>

  <%= player_form.label :firstname, class: "az-form__label" %> <br/>
  <%= player_form.text_field :firstname, class: "az-form__input", placeholder: "Firstname of player", autofocus: true %>

  <%= player_form.label :lastname, class: "az-form__label" %> </br>
  <%= player_form.text_field :lastname, class: "az-form__input", placeholder: "Lastname of player" %>

  <%= player_form.fields_for :player_games, @player.initialized_player_games do |builder| %>

    <% @game = builder.object.game %>

    <%= render 'result_fields', f: builder %>

    <div class="links">
      <%= link_to_add_association 'add result', player_form, :player_games, :partial => 'players/result_fields' %>
    </div>

    <hr>

  <% end %>

  <div class="text-center">
    <%= button_tag(type: "submit", class: "az-form__submit") do %>
        <%= player_form.object.new_record? ? "Create player" : "Update player" %>
    <% end %>
  </div>

<% end %>
```

## _result_fields.html.erb

```
<div class="nested-fields">

<%= f.hidden_field :game_id, :value => @game.id%>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <label class="az-form__label az-form__label--unable js-az-form__checkbox" data-check="<%= @game.id %>">
      <%= f.check_box :enable %>
      <%= @game.title %>
     </label>
  </div>
 </div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <%= f.label :score,
                    class: "az-form__label", :data => {:check => @game.id } %> </br>
     <%= f.number_field :score, step: :any, :data => {:check => @game.id },
                           class: "az-form__input az-form__input--disabled",
                           placeholder: "Score for '#{@game.title}'", disabled: true %>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6">
     <%= f.label :time,
                    class: "az-form__label", :data => {:check => @game.id } %> </br>
  <%= f.number_field :time, step: :any, :data => {:check => @game.id },
                           class: "az-form__input az-form__input--disabled",
                           placeholder: "Time for '#{@game.title}'", disabled: true %>
   </div>
 </div>

 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12">
   <%= link_to_remove_association "remove result", f %>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

## Question:

When edit 'player' have access to only one result per game, can not change others, conflict with 'initialized_player_games' method, but if i remove this method from form work well, but cannot create another game if dont create in new action, how can i change this method properly?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you want to add an entry for all games (which works), but adding a new `Result` does not. The problem is the `@game` which is probable either undefined or set to the last game.

I also do not really like the approach (giving the `fields_for` a specific set). Instead I would adapt the approach slightly. Instead of using `initialized_player_games` I would use a method, to be called in the controller, e.g. `add_default_player_games`, something like

```
def add_default_player_games 
  Game.all.each do |game|
    if g = player_games.find { |g| g.game_id == game.id }
      g.enable ||= true 
    else
      player_games.build(game: game)
    end
  end
end
```

effectively adding new instances to the collection, without saving them.

So in your controller you would write

```
 @player = Player.new
 @player.add_default_player_games
```

or in `edit`

```
 @player = Player.find(params[:id])
 @player.add_default_player_games
```

Your view would then just iterate over `player_games`

```
<%= player_form.fields_for :player_games do |builder| %>
  <%= render 'result_fields', f: builder %>
<% end %>
```

And then, if you would use `simple-form` it would be very easy to select a game if not yet selected, and there is no need for the ugly `@game`.

So do something like in `_result_fields` (in haml because I am a lazy typist)

```
.nested-fields
  - game_id = f.object.game_id 
  - if game_id.present? 
    = f.hidden_field :game_id
  - else 
    = f.collection_select :game_id, Game.all, :id, :name
  ...
```

So in short: if there is a `game_id`, do not allow to change it (would be useful to show the title of the game or something), but if not use a dropdown-select to choose the game.
And the rest stays the same (only use `game_id` instead of `@game.id`).

Comment: Your method works fine, now im trying to rebuild form with 'sample_form', by the way i have a error on 'f.collection_select :game_id, Game.all.map{|g| [g.name, g.id]} ' -> 'Wrong number of arguments', so i removed this if statement and it works for now

Comment: I wrote this code as an example, did not test it. I fixed the `collection_select` definition. If you do not need to set the game at all, then you do not need the select, to me it seemed relevant to actually be able to select the game for which to add the score. But it was just an example (and you could use any of the alternative ways to create a dropdown select option).